# Subtracting the values of two dictionaries

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I am trying to subtract dict1 - dict2. It does not matter if the result is a negative number for the dogs, I am just interested in learning the concept :)

```
owner = ['Bob', 'Sarah', 'Ann']

dict1 = {'Bob': {'shepherd': [4,6,3],'collie': [23, 3, 45], 'poodle':[2,0,6]}, {'Sarah': {'shepherd': [1,2,3],'collie': [3, 31, 4], 'poodle': [21,5,6]},{'Ann': {'shepherd': [4,6,3],'collie': [23, 3, 45], 'poodle': [2,10,8]}}


 dict2 = {'Bob': {'shepherd': 10,'collie': 15,'poodle': 34},'Sarah': {'shepherd': 3,'collie': 25,'poodle': 4},'Ann': {'shepherd': 2,'collie': 1,'poodle': 0}}
```

I want:

```
wanted =   dict1 = {'Bob': {'shepherd': [-6,-4,-7],'collie': [8, -12, 30], 'poodle':[-32,-34,-28]}, {'Sarah': {'shepherd': [-2,-1,0],'collie': [-22, 6, -21], 'poodle': [17,1,2]},{'Ann': {'shepherd': [2,4,1],'collie': [22, 2, 44], 'poodle': [2,10,8]}}
```

I am still new to dictionaries so here is what I have been trying but get NoneType error. I am assuming it is because dict1 has more values than dict2, but I cannot find a way to perform the above computation.

```
wanted = {}

for i in owner:
    wanted.update({i: dict1.get(i) - dict2.get(i)})
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a nested dictionary comprehension. I tweaked your dictionary a bit because it wasn't correct syntax (there were a few extra curly braces). There is no need for an owners array because we can just use the keys in the dictionaries.

```
dict1 = {
    'Bob': {
        'shepherd': [4, 6, 3],
        'collie': [23, 3, 45],
        'poodle': [2, 0, 6],
    },
    'Sarah': {
        'shepherd': [1, 2, 3],
        'collie': [3, 31, 4],
        'poodle': [21, 5, 6],
    },
    'Ann': {
        'shepherd': [4, 6, 3],
        'collie': [23, 3, 45],
        'poodle': [2, 10, 8],
    }
}
dict2 = {
    'Bob': {'shepherd': 10, 'collie': 15, 'poodle': 34},
    'Sarah': {'shepherd': 3, 'collie': 25, 'poodle': 4},
    'Ann': {'shepherd': 2, 'collie': 1, 'poodle': 0},
}
wanted = {
    owner: {
        dog: [num - dict2[owner][dog] for num in num_list]
        for dog, num_list in dog_dict.iteritems()
    } for owner, dog_dict in dict1.iteritems()
}
print wanted
```

Output:

```
{
    'Sarah': {
        'shepherd': [-2, -1, 0],
        'collie': [-22, 6, -21],
        'poodle': [17, 1, 2]
    },
    'Bob': {
        'shepherd': [-6, -4, -7],
        'collie': [8, -12, 30],
        'poodle': [-32, -34, -28]
    },
    'Ann': {
        'shepherd': [2, 4, 1],
        'collie': [22, 2, 44],
        'poodle': [2, 10, 8]
    }
}
```

This is assuming that dict2 has all of the same keys as dict1. If that's not the case, you'll need to set some default values to avoid a `KeyError`.

**EDIT**: Here's a brief explanation of how to interpret the dictionary comprehension for those not familiar with it. If you're more comfortable with list comprehensions, a dictionary comprehension is very similar, only you create a dictionary instead of a list. So, `{i: str(i) for i in xrange(10)}` will give you a dictionary of `{0: '0', 1: '1', ..., 9: '9'}`.

Now we can apply that to the solution. This code:

```
wanted = {
    owner: {
        dog: [num - dict2[owner][dog] for num in num_list]
        for dog, num_list in dog_dict.iteritems()
    } for owner, dog_dict in dict1.iteritems()
}
```

is equivalent to:

```
wanted = {}
for owner, dog_dict in dict1.iteritems():
    wanted[owner] = {}
    for dog, num_list in dog_dict.iteritems():
        wanted[owner][dog] = [num - dict2[owner][dog] for num in num_list]
```

Comment: Could you please explain the idea of nested dictionary comprehension? At lease how to iterate over dict1. The problem is very interesting, but answer is convoluted to me.

Comment: @Monica: I don't agree that the answer is convoluted: it is the most straightforward and pythonic way of doing it. What may confuse you at first is the fact that you have 3 nested list/dict comprehensions. To make sense of it, try to break them down 1 by 1 from inside out.

Comment: @Monica - I've added a footnote to try to explain nested dictionary comprehensions a bit. The key is just to step through each layer. As Julien pointed out, this is a pretty Pythonic construct and worth learning about :)

Comment: @Karin. Thank you for a footnote! It helps a lot! I wasn't familiar with the dictionary comprehension and I didn't want to offended you or so.

Comment: @Monica - No offense taken at all! I'm glad you asked, as I expect the footnote may also help others who see this answer in the future :)

Comment: Thank you very much as well as the edit. I spent such a long time trying to figure this out.

Comment: @Karin Do you visit a chatroom? I'd love to ask you a question not related to this topic. There is no private messaging to speak to another user.